# Unable to extract images from *.bag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data ,but
"rosmake image_view --rosdep-install"            gives an error
"rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install".
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137886/unable-to-extract-images-from-*.bag/) by [akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/13061/akash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed ros-hydro-desktop-full by

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

as stated in

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu

image_view typically comes along with the installation and does not have to be installed as separate package. Just continue with what is following in the tutorial....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/13061/akash/) on 2014-03-10**:
Proceeding further,  "roslaunch export.launch"    gives the error

process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [5274]
[FATAL] [1394450389.001846739]: Error opening file: play
process[extract-2]: started with pid [5286]
[ INFO] [1394450389.280192931]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
[rosbag-1] process has died [pid 5274, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosbag/play play -d 2 /opt/ros/hydro/share/image_view/first.bag __name:=rosbag __log:=/home/master/.ros/log/d6ea7ee6-a841-11e3-8d46-60eb69709e0d/rosbag-1.log].

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-10**:
This tutorial requires that you have previously recorded a bag file which contains image data you would like to export as jpeg images or video.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-10**:
Record a rosbag with an image stream and change args of the rosbag node in launch according to where your bag file is placed. Futhermore the remap tag of image_view node has to be set to the image topic you have recorded into your rosbag

**Comment by [akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/13061/akash/) on 2014-03-10**:
my export.launch file
"




</node

> "

```
-- MY "rosbag info first.bag"  OUTPUT--------
```

path:        first.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    2:10s (130s)
start:       Feb 03 2014 07:51:42.82 (1391394102.82)
end:         Feb 03 2014 07:53:53.55 (1391394233.55)
size:        47.3 MB
messages:    1056
compression: none [61/61 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/CompressedImage [8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]
topics:      /front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed   1056 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-10**:

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-10**:
You can try this one. I am not sure whether image_view can handle compressed images, though. Maybe also try to record image_raw of your camera....